# bash script variable substitution in curl command

Tags: bash, curl

I have a curl command that looks like this

`curl --silent -H 'Authorization:Bearer sdfsdfsfd/1Fdsdfsdfdf' https://example.com/api`

Running this command as is via terminal returns the expected results.

I am trying to incorporate this curl command in my bash script as follows:

```
OPTS_HOST='https://example.com/api'
OPTS_USER='Authorization:Bearer sdfsdfsfd/1Fdsdfsdfdf'
OPTS_CURL="--silent"
CURL_CMD="curl $OPTS_CURL -H"

$CURL_CMD \'$OPTS_USER\' $OPTS_HOST
```

the output of this seems to be an unexpected HTML error page.

Pretty sure it is something to do with the bearer token interpretation in the command.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
TIA

Comment: you don't appear to understand how shell quoting works. instead of `\'$OPTS_USER\'` you should be using `"$OPTS_USER"`

Comment: Also, tangentially, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050